# problem in creating php sessions from get variables

Tags: php

i have following in my url
http://www.foo.com/?token=foo&tokenid=fooid
now i want to get those token and tokenid value and create sessions from both values...
i have following in my php code

```
$em = $_GET['token'];
$emid = $_GET['tokenid'];
$_SESSION['foo'] = $em;
$_SESSION['fooid'] = $emid;
```

but it is not creating sessions ... how can i solve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you remember `session_start()` before assigning the values?

See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) if you are in doubt.

If you really mean that you want to create a session from the tokens you should have look at [session_id()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php).

Comment: yess i have include session_start(); also please let me know how i create sessions from session id

Comment: What is it that you wish to obtain? To fetch the session defined by the token id? Then you just pass the ID you want for your session before you call session_start().